# Reload website in ubuntu-touch browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser, phone

Is there a way to refresh the content of a website in the browser of ubuntu-touch phones?
I am using BQ Aquaris 4.5 with 14.10 (r21).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the address bar and there is on the left site a button to reload. The button is in the address bar – left from the internet address.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the address bar to pretend to start editing the web address and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the virtual keyboard.

Comment: As a walk-around this works for sure and is what I was doing so far. I was actually wondering if there was an option/ button to do so, that I might have overlooked. Thanks for your help  :)